# How to pass interface through web sockets in asp.net and angular?

Tags: asp.net, angular, websocket

I'm working on a project with a backend that is written in ASP.NET and an Angular 6 frontend.

I want to pass data through web sockets. This data contains multiple classes that are connected to one interface. When I send the data with one class without inner classes and interfaces it works but not when I use the interface.

On the Angular side classes:

```
export class SocketMessage {
constructor(
public ID: string,
public Body: ISocketMessageType) { }
};

interface ISocketMessageType {
GetMessage(): string;
}

export class A implements ISocketMessageType {
public message: string;

public GetMessage() {
  return this.message;
}
constructor(message: string) {
    this.message = JSON.stringify(message);
    }
}

export class B implements ISocketMessageType
{
    public message: string;

    public GetMessage() {
        return this.message;
     }

      constructor(start: boolean) {
          this.message = JSON.stringify(start);
      }
 }

export class C implements ISocketMessageType {
    public message: string;

    public GetMessage() {
        return this.message;
    }
    constructor(var1: number) {
        this.message = JSON.stringify(speed);
    }
}
```

Angular link side:

```
  connectToDevice() {
      this.socketService.connect().subscribe(
       (data) => {
         debugger;
        this.checkData(data);
      }
    );
  }

  checkData(data: SocketMessage) {
    if (data.Body instanceof A) {
      var info = data.Body as A;
      alert(info.message);
      this.router.navigate(['Home']);
    }
  }
}
```

Server side:

```
[Serializable]
public class SocketMessage
{
    public string ID{ get; }
    public ISocketMessageType Body { get; }

    public SocketMessage (string ID, ISocketMessageType body)
    {
        this.ID= ID;
        this.Body = body;
    }
}

public interface ISocketMessageType
{
    string GetMessage();
}

[Serializable]
public class A: ISocketMessageType
{
    private string message;
    public string GetMessage()
    {
        return message;
    }

    public A(string msg)
    {
        this.message= message;
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class B: ISocketMessageType
{
    private bool start;
    public string GetMessage()
    {
        return start.ToString();
    }

    public B(bool start)
    {
        this.start = start;
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class C: ISocketMessageType
{
    private double var1;
    public string GetMessage()
    {
        return speed.ToString();
    }

    public C(double var1)
    {
        this.var1 = var1;
    }
}
```

But my output is ID:18 (that is correct) and body {}
Why?